# Akka http Explicitly set HTTP header 'Content-Type: application/json' is ignored

Tags: json, scala, akka-http

I have code like:

```
val request = HttpRequest(
      method = HttpMethods.POST,
      uri = Uri(url))
      .withHeaders(List(authorization, ctJson))
      .withEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, ByteString(jsonStr))
 Http().singleRequest(request)
```

which works fine but I have a warning during request:

> Explicitly set HTTP header 'Content-Type: application/json' is
>   ignored, explicit `Content-Type` header is not allowed. Set
>   `HttpRequest.entity.contentType` instead.

How to resolve this issue ? Ive tried also:

```
val request = HttpRequest(
      HttpMethods.POST,
      uri = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send",
      entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, ByteString(jsonStr)),
      headers = List(authorization, ctJson))
```

but the same result..

Comment: What is the `ctJson` header? If it's `application/json`, you don't need that and that's what Akka-Http is complaining about.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you added the proper content type to the entity, but you need to remove the `ctJson` header.